# How to execute JS in JSX (React) without outputting it as HTML?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

How would you assemble this html using jsx/react. My problem is that `i++` is always output as part of the html, although it is something I'd rather want to execute.

```js
const rows = [];

for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  let row;
  if (i + 1 < items.length) {
    // on all but the last item we have to items in a row
    row = (
      <div className="bpa-module-tile-row">
        {this.getItem(items[i])}
        i++;
        {this.getItem(items[i])}
        )
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    // if we have an odd number of items, then the last row has only one not two items in a rowj
    row = (
      <div className="bpa-module-tile-row">{this.getItem(items[i])}</div>
    );
  }

  rows.push(row);
}
```

The `rows` are then output later using `{rows}` in jsx. The problem is that the `i++` result also ends up in the html. I feel like I am "thinking" or approaching it in a wrong way here.

How can I write this in idiomatic JSX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to increment your counter by 2 and calculate each index as appropriate:

```
const rows = [];

for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i += 2) {
  let row;
  if (i + 1 < items.length) {
    // on all but the last item we have to items in a row
    row = (
      <div className="bpa-module-tile-row">
        {this.getItem(items[i])}
        {this.getItem(items[i+1])}
        )
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    // if we have an odd number of items, then the last row has only one not two items in a rowj
    row = (
      <div className="bpa-module-tile-row">{this.getItem(items[i])}</div>
    );
  }

  rows.push(row);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's the root cause fix, hence cleanest solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) will iterate through the list and produce another list applying the function you provide it.

Something similar to this is what you're looking for:

```
const items = [1,2,3,4,5]
const rows = items.map((_, index) => index % 2 ? [] : items.slice(index, index + 2))
  .filter(row => row.length > 0)
  .map(row =>
     (<div className="bpa-module-tile-row">
       {row.map(x => "Item " + x)}
     </div>)
  );
```

Try it out: [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d9mbmrya/)

---

If you can import (or [write your own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495687/split-array-into-chunks)) [**chunk**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#chunk) method then this becomes even more simple:

```
const rows = chunk(items, size=2)
 .map(row =>
     (<div className="bpa-module-tile-row">
       {row.map(x => "Item " + x)}
     </div>)
  );
```

Comment: I cannot try atm, but why would this not add the index to the row? That's what I want to avoid. Also, I need to process 2 indexes at once unless it is the last and odd index.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. You only seem to be maintaining one index in your example. I've edited my answer slightly to try and guess what you're looking for but if you can provide more detail I can help further.

Comment: Also what does `getItem` do? It seems rather confusing to pass an `item` to that

Comment: This will repeat items. The first `div` will contain the items at indices 0 and 1, the next `div` will contain items at indices 1 and 2, etc. The original code outputs items at 0 and 1 then items at 2 and 3, etc.

Comment: Edited, to avoid the dups.

Comment: @ᴘᴀɴᴀʏɪᴏᴛɪs  +1 because it works and is really the most brainfuck code :) (but I'll accept another answer)

Comment: @nachtigall Nothing beats the readability of adding a helper method :) (see my edit)

Answer (score 1):

You can simple use i++ whereever you want inside the curly braces. Your row object must be like:

```
row = (
      <div className="bpa-module-tile-row">
        {this.getItem(items[i++])}
        {this.getItem(items[i])}
        )
      </div>
    );
```

Comment: Well, I am not a friend of these "hidden" i++ statements. Really easy to overlook. I'd prefer if the i++ would be a statement on a single line.